# iptables "host/network not found" with an exclamation mark IP address

Tags: iptables, ip

I'm trying to add a `iptables` rule in order to drop any incoming packets except those from a specific IP. Following the manual, I try to run this:

```
    > iptables -t filter -I INPUT -s !12.34.56.78 -p tcp -j DROP
```

but I get this error:

```
    iptables v1.4.12.1: host/network `!12.34.56.78' not found
```

The manpages say  for `-s / --src / --source` parameter `...  A "!" argument before the  address  specification  inverts  the sense of the address. ...`.

The first issue I had with this exclamation mark was that the shell expanded it to a command from history. The solution `set +H` was applied and it seems it's not an issue anymore.

**Why the exclamation mark is not accepted to specify an inverted address as manual says?**

PS: Of course I have tried to use it with a space between `!` and IP and it's not accepted.

**EDIT**
Just before accepting an answer, maybe anyone could also help with an answer to: why the order of parameters should be `! -s {IP}` instead of `-s !{IP}` as the manual says?  just a newer version of `iptables` changed this syntax while keeping old man pages?  or is it somehow configurable?

Comment: what error message do you get when you use a space between ! and the IP?

Comment: When there is a space between ! and IP I get this `Bad argument '12.34.56.78'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a space between `!` and the IP address

```
 iptables -t filter -I INPUT -s ! 12.34.56.78 -p tcp -j DROP
```

If you get a message like `Using intrapositioned negation (`--option ! this`) is deprecated in favor of extrapositioned (`! --option this`).`

Then Place the ! before the "-s" option as in -

```
 iptables -t filter -I INPUT ! -s 12.34.56.78 -p tcp -j DROP
```

Comment: Well, it seems the solution with the `!` before `-s` is accepted, thanks. Do you know why it has this behaviour? Just got access to another system with `iptables` (v1.4.10) and it accepts `-s !12.34.56.78` as the manual states.

Comment: Never encountered same problem. Chances are it is a syntax change introduced with latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try escaping the ! from your shell?

```
iptables -A INPUT \! -s 12.34.56.78 -p tcp -j DROP
```

EDIT: My apologies, I see you've accounted for escaping the !, so you just have the order wrong.  The command I pasted above works fine on my machines, should do for you.

Comment: Thanks, it works wiht this order, but my order is not wrong according to manual. It seems the manual doesn't keep track with the implementation. I've got access to another system with `iptables` (v1.4.10) and it works as I was trying. Do you know why this works so? Is it configurable or just a newer version changed the syntax while keeping old `man`?